# Screen off and lock-screen behavior for NFC traffic

Tags: android, nfc

So I was looking through the Android Developer Docs. I came across the following page:
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/nfc/hce

At that specific page, it states the following:

> Current Android implementations turn the NFC controller and the
>   application processor off completely when the screen of the device is
>   turned off. HCE services will therefore not work when the screen is
>   off.

Apparently not all manufacturers obey this rule of thumb. Some devices are still able to have NFC communication when the screen is turned off. Is there a standard workaround to check whether the screen is on and not allow NFC communication whatsoever?

Answer (score 0):

As this question has not been answered by anyone else, I will post my solution. Unfortunately it is the case that some devices still respond to NFC traffic although they shouldn't do that.

I made a small utility class that tells you whether the display is off or not.

```
class DisplayUtils(private val context: Context) {

    fun isScreenOff() = getDisplay()?.state == Display.STATE_OFF

    private fun getDisplay() = (context.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE) as? WindowManager)?.defaultDisplay
}
```

If the display is off, I don't allow any NFC traffic to take place. Benefits of this solution:

- It does not require any additional permission.
- It does not require the registration of any broadcastreceiver.

Hopefully this can help someone.